# Vanilla JavaScript to show scroll progress bar that fills only while scrolling the <main> element?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a scroll progress bar that fills from 0-100% when scrolling the element only, but i can't get it to work. I've got it working to show the whole page scrolling progress when scrolling the element, but I need it to only show 0-100% on the element, and only while that element is being scrolled. I also need to create it using vanilla javascript.

Here's what i have that isn't working:

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <section>
        </section>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="scroll">
                <div class="scroll-bar" id="scroll-progress"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section>
            <p>some content</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>some content</p>
        </section>
    </main>
    <section>
        <p>some content</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>some content</p>
    </section>
    
</body>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    background-color: black;
    height:50px;
}
section {
    height: 400px;
}

.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#scroll-progress {
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const progress = () => {
    const scroll = main.scrollTop;
    const height = main.scrollHeight - main.clientHeight;
    const scrollProgress = (scroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById('scroll-progress').style.width = scrollProgress + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', progress);
```

This, however, works as expected, but shows the progress through the whole page, while scrolling the element, I'm just not sure how to get from this to what i need.

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const progress = () => {
    let scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    let scrollProgress = (scroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("scroll-progress").style.width = scrollProgress + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', progress);
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm sure you're right, it just seemed the neater solution to delete and rewrite, than editing a question that it was rightfully pointed out was unclear and too long. I apologise if I'm committing a major faux pas; I was going for ease and simplicity in the question, not faster answers

Comment: is that `main` element large enough to have a scroll of it's own to make this work?

Comment: Assuming that you fix your js. If your main element doesn't have a scroll of its own, then the scroll event listener won't trigger because there's no scroll behavior happening within that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things are missing.

1. you need to attach the scroll handler to the `main` element, not the window.
2. the main element won't scroll as-is, you need to give it either a height, or a max-height and an `overflow-y: auto`

```css
.nav {
    background-color: black;
    height:50px;
}

main {
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
section {
    height: 400px;
}

.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#scroll-progress {
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

js

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const scrollProgress = document.getElementById('scroll-progress')

const progress = () => {
    const scroll = main.scrollTop;
    const height = main.scrollHeight - main.clientHeight;
    const percent = (scroll / height) * 100;
    scrollProgress.style.width = percent + "%";
}

main.addEventListener('scroll', progress);
```

Notice I moved the scroll-progress selector outside the `process` callback, so that the query only runs once.
Here's a working demo: https://codepen.io/jacob_124/pen/QWzQGBP

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful, and thanks for the scroll-progress selector tip - I didn't even think of that!

Comment: @KirstyF If this solved your problem, would you mind marking this as the correct answer, please?